# Difference between "%d" and "%d " at scanf in C language

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace, format-specifiers, format-string

If I code like below

```
int main()
{
    int num;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then input "1 2 3", the output is

```
enter an integer
1 2 3
1
enter an integer
2
enter an integer
3
```

I know this is because buffer contains 1, 2, 3 at a time when input

however when I add space from "%d" to "%d " at scanf and input same thing "1 2 3" like before,

the output is

```
enter an integer
1 2 3
1
enter an integer
2
enter an integer
```

It didn't keep going like before with small change with "%d "

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Difference between “%d” and “%d ” at scanf in C language

The difference is that when you use "%d " as format string, `scanf()`continues to consume white-space characters until it has encountered another non-white space character, like for example 2,3,4. A simply newline `\n` or another white space character after the input number won´t break the consuming.

Whereas when you use "%d" only without white space after the format specifier, a white space character such as newline `\n` breaks the consuming.

---

> It didn't keep going like before with small change with "%d "
>
> Why does this happen?

The reason is because `scanf("%d ", &num);` after it has consumed the `3` at the third walkthrough of the for-loop, still is consuming trailing white space **until** it has found another character.

The `3` is not printed, because `scanf()`still is consuming. The whole program will get only finished if you enter another character like `4`, in that specific case. This will work because the for-loop only has 3 walkthroughs of its body. If it would has more than this would even not work. You need to have one more character in `stdin` as you have walkthroughs of the for-loop with this kind of program.

Comment: "_The whole program will get only finished if you enter another character...._" -- Signalling end of file from the keyboard with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-C (Windows) will also work.

Comment: @exnihilo Indeed exactly; but this requires the action from the user. Would the user not do anything or another program writes characters in `stdin`, the program won´t stop from its own hand with this buffer.

Comment: The point is that `scanf()` will not return until a match fails _or_ end of file is reached. "_You need to have one more character_" is not quite right. If input is redirected from a file, `scanf()` will return when end of file is reached. My answer on the duplicate question discusses this.

Comment: @exnihilo At the third invoke of `scanf()` when the 3 is getting consumed, it searches for another non-white character. If it would encounter one, for example 4, it should end the respective consumption, `scanf()` would return, the 3 get printed with the next `printf()` and because the loop has no further iterations, the program will be getting finished. Anyway, I´ve not already seen the answer and discussion of yours in the duplicate. I will take a look on it now.

Comment: @exnihilo Ok, I´ve read it now. +1 for your answer. -  I understand now what you mean - When it encounters the end of file the consumption will also be failed and scanf() is returnning `EOF`. Yes, I have forget to mention that. I will take that into my answer.

Comment: @exnihilo So, my assumption that the program would not terminate is wrong, right? It terminates; `scanf()` is returning `EOF` in that case, but the following `printf()` just can´t print it out to the terminal.

Comment: "_`scanf()` is returning EOF_" -- note that `scanf()` only returns EOF when there is an input failure (rare) before the first conversion; otherwise it returns the number of successful conversions. You are _right_ that `scanf()` does not terminate in the above code, unless the input has been redirected from a file in which case end of file will cause `scanf()` to return. If the user inputs either another character (as you suggested) _or_ if they signal EOF from the keyboard, `scanf()` will also return. In all of those cases the final `printf()` will be executed.

Comment: @exnihilo What do you mean with "redirected from a file" exactly? I thought we talk only about the file of `stdin`? And why does it come in all cases to the final `printf()` - *In all of those cases the final printf() will be executed.* - if `scanf()` won´t terminate?

Comment: If the user types the input, pressing enter after the 3 as OP did, `scanf()` will wait indefinitely for more input. If that input is a whitespace, it will match and continue waiting. If that input is a non-whitespace character, the match fails, `scanf()` returns and the final `printf()` executes. If instead, after pressing [ENTER], the user signals eof with Ctrl-D, `scanf()` will return and the final `printf()` executes. Or, if a file contains "1 2 3 [any amount of whitespace]", eof will be reached and `scanf()` will return and the final `printf()` executes. Here, e.g. `a.out < file.txt`.